# Is it possible to upload/download files to another person's Google drive using the drive API?

Tags: api, google-drive-api

It is for an application which has sensitive user data. Could we just store this data in that person's Google Drive using the drive API?

Also is it possible to access it later when needed?

The documentation wasn't very clear about this. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the user gives authorization to the App, yes, [it is possible](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth). To do so you need to set Oauth2, which will give you [Access](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/) and [Refresh Tokens](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/refreshing-access-tokens/). Make sure you use the lowest scope possible ([drive.file](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#drive) should be enough in your case). You might also be more interested in using the [AppData folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/appdata) if you only want to access the data with the App.